# F# Guid.Parse TypeInitializationException

Tags: exception, f#

I'm working on a WebApi project written in F#. Here a snippet:

```
module MyModule

open System

let MyGuid = Guid.Parse "934F0B12-D00A-491D-862D-EE745EF3C560"

let myFunction list = 
    list.Get(MyGuid) // --> here MyGuid has the TypeInitializationException before list.Get is called
```

By debugging I can see that the MyGuid actually has an error

Changing the code followings, it works:

```
module MyModule

open System

let MyGuid () = Guid.Parse "934F0B12-D00A-491D-862D-EE745EF3C560"

let myFunction list = 
    list.Get(MyGuid())
```

I actually know the MyGuid of the first example is a variable and the second one a function definition, but why does the first rise the exception? I my code MyGuid is used some times. so in the first example I'd have only one instance, in the second a new instance every time MyGuid is called...

Comment: What's the type of `list` and what's `list.Get`?

Comment: What's the text of `TypeInitializationException`? Its `InnerException`?

Comment: It doesn't matter what `list` and `list.Get` are, at this point the `MyGuid` is already `faulty`. 
Can't see Innerexceptions, only ` 'MyGuid' threw an exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that this is the problem here, but I've seen similar behaviour when using unit test runners sometimes. My guess is that the error happens because the top-level `MyGuid` variable is not initialized correctly and has the default zero value (and as a result, the lookup fails).

The way global variables are initialized in F# is tricky - if you compile code as executable, this can happen from the `Main` method. But if you compile code as a library, the compiler inserts an initialization checks into static constructors of the types in your library (to make sure everything is initialized before you access anything).

I think this can break if you compile your code as an executable, but then load it as a library - the entry-point is not called and so the variables are not initialized. I'm not sure how exactly WebApi loads libraries, but this could be a problem - especially if you compile the F# code as an executable.

Your workaround of turning the global variable into a function fixes this, because the function is compiled as a method and so you avoid referring to an uninitialized value. Sadly, I don't think there is a better workaround for this.

Comment: As mentioned, the problem is not the lookup by calling `list.Get`. By setting a breakpoint at this line, the Guid has this TypeInitializationException inside, instead the Guid instance. I'm working on a web project `WebApi`, at this point I think it is a sort of bug.

Comment: @Emaborsa I see this got marked as the answer - what was the issue behind this? Was my guess close, or was it something else?

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is. I turned the static variables into functions. If it where a bigger project I would create a sort of singleton module/class in order to avoid multiple instances of the same guid.